# Magento 2: Use Categories Path for Product URLs is not working

Tags: magento2, product, category, url-rewrite, paths

I have two products having the same attributes as categories, attribute set, etc. And I have set `Use Categories Path for Product URLs` as `NO` but still, one product has the category in URL another don't

Why is this happening?
I run

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush
```